# Bootstrap select not returning values in the 'changed' fired event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-select

Using [Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events)  events

The 'newValue' and 'oldValue' in the callback function isn't returning any value, they are returning true and false respectively, but according to the documentation from the link above they should be returning values right?

```js
$('#instructorLocationRadius').off('changed.bs.select').on('changed.bs.select', function(event, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
  scope.locationDistanceSearched = newValue; // newValue is returning true
});
```

```html
<select id="instructorLocationRadius" class="selectpicker btn-group-lg" style="border-radius: 0px; color: #777;">
  <option class="distance" value="2">2 miles</option>
  <option class="distance" value="5">5 miles</option>
  <option class="distance" value="8">8 miles</option>
  <option class="distance" value="15">15 miles</option>
  <option class="distance" value="25">25 miles</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
$('#instructorLocationRadius').on('changed.bs.select', function(event, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
  scope.locationDistanceSearched = newValue; // newValue is returning true
});
```

Comment: removing .off() does not effect the returned values

Comment: do you have the cdn of bootstrap select on your project?
working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/153401/

Comment: not sure if I read the doc corectly, but I obtained the value by using this.value and not newValue...

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1378 will help